# Ruby how do I create an array with array's value as an object

Tags: java, arrays, ruby, data-structures

So I want to create this type of array. Note that this array has duplicate values. So I can't use hashMap's.

```
arr = [3,4,6,4,9,0]
```

I should also be able to do this:

```
arr[0].value = 9
arr[1].value = 10
```

Please help me with this type of data structure.  It would be great if I can get one example of Java and one of Ruby.
Another easier to understand example.

```
arr['tom','jack', 'Ian','sam']
```

I wanna add a property of lastName to each array element. So my data structure so after adding this property.

```
arr['tom'].lastName = 'smith'
arr['jack'].lastName = 'parker'
arr['ian'].lastName = 'jones'
...
```

Now from a query perspective. if I call

```
arr[0] -> 'tom'
arr[0].lastName -> 'smith'
```

These are the results I am trying to retreive

Comment: just `arr[0] = 9` in ruby

Comment: however, for the above given array, it will be `arr[0] = 3` is this you looking for?

Comment: No I can't do that because there are duplicate elements in my array. So in my initial array I have duplicate values. @SergioTulentsev

Comment: @Rub-dev98: this didn't help much. You certainly _can_ do that. You may not _want to_, but, at the moment, I have no idea why.

Comment: @Rub-dev98: also, suppose the syntax from your question worked. What effect would you expect it to cause?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Updated the description of problem with another example.

Comment: @Rub-dev98: can't do that with array. but you can use a hash where key is a string and value is your custom class which has `last_name` property or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Your intent is not really clear so I'll assume you want to replace values in your array. In ruby, you can do :

```
irb(main):001:0> a = [3, 4, 6, 4, 9, 0]
[]
irb(main):002:0> a[1]
4
irb(main):003:0> a[1] = 10
10
irb(main):004:0> a
[3, 10, 6, 4, 9, 0]
```

Comment: Can't do that because let's assume  arr = [3,4,6,4,9,0] then I wish to assign a[1].value  =  10 and  a[3].value = 15.  whereas a[1] and a[3] are both equal to 4. So if I do a[1] I get 4 and if I do a[1].value then I get 10.

Comment: Ok, then ? What do you want to do exactly ?

Comment: I don't see any problem here. You can re-assign any value of your array by doing `arr[i] = new_value` regardless of this value being present more than one time in your array. With your example, if you issue `a[1] = 10` and `a[3] = 15` in ruby, then your array will become equal to `[3, 10, 6, 15, 9, 0]`. You tell ruby to replace a value at a *given* index, it doesn't care about the value in place but the index at which you want to update the value.

Comment: Correct me if m wrong. Maybe I should have used a better example. Lets say I wanna store these values. arr=['tom','jack, 'ian', 'sam'] . Now I also wanna save the last names. So I can add arr['tom'].last = 'smith' and arr['jack'].last = 'parker' ... and so on. So I need a data structure like this:
arr[0] will return 'tom' and arr[0].last will return 'smith'

Comment: When you do `arr[0].list` with your array, you are calling `last` on a string. To achieve what you want to do, you will need to define an object representing a user that responds to the method `last` (last name) and `first` (first name).